# Use Angular variable in Rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs, haml

I'm using Angularjs in parts of my Rails app, which works great. But I'm wondering how to use an Angular value inside a link_to.

Here is my pseudo code:

```
%table          
  %tr{"ng-repeat" => "book in books"}
    %td
      {{book.title}}
    %td= link_to "Show", book_url({{book.id}})
```

This gives me an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC
```

This could also have to do with HAML causing the error, but how can I send the ID in the link_to?

Comment: Instead of a "link_to", I can of course use a normal link:                   %a{href: 'books/{{book.id}}'}
  'Show'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a "link_to", I can of course use a normal link:

```
%a{href: 'books/{{book.id}}'} 'Show'
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
<li ng-repeat="deal in deals">
    <%= link_to 'show,'#','ng-href' => "#{deals_path()}/{{deal.id}}" %>
</li>
```

Comment: Wont anything after the # be treated as a comment and therefore not work?

Comment: @Linus: no, the # is inside a string.

Comment: Oh yes you're absolutely right, it was just Atom not being able to display the syntax correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It work fine:

```
= link_to 'Show', URI::unescape(books_path('{{book._id}}'))
```